# How to parse csv data, to show certain rows as columns

Tags: python, csv

I want to show the row value as a column for a values in a certain column

Raw data

```
For eg

_time                         action    file
2019-07-24T02:01:02.930-0400    get     abc
2019-07-24T00:30:10.927-0400    put     abc
2019-07-24T05:01:02.930-0400    get     def
2019-07-24T04:30:10.927-0400    put     def
```

and so on

I want the output to be

```
File  put                            get
abc  2019-07-24T00:30:10.927-0400    2019-07-24T02:01:02.930-0400
def  2019-07-24T04:30:10.927-0400    2019-07-24T05:01:02.930-0400
```

I was thinking i can do it in for loop? so

```
with open('raw.csv','r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for line in csv_reader:
                if line[0] != "":
                        file = line[0]
                           if line[1] == "get" and file in {file}
                                   gettime = line[1]
                           if line[1] == "put" and file in {file}
                                   puttime = line[1]
                print file,puttime,gettime
```

This doesnt work though

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" - error message, wrong answer, infinite loop, ...? Also what you show as "raw data" has no commas. So are you looking at it in Excel or something? Can you show the actual raw data?

Comment: Maybe do it in 2 passes? Read the data into a dict keyed by file. Then create the output with one row per file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) routine:

```
In [9]: df.pivot_table(index='file', columns='action', values='_time', aggfunc='first')                           
Out[9]: 
action                           get                           put
file                                                              
abc     2019-07-24T02:01:02.930-0400  2019-07-24T00:30:10.927-0400
def     2019-07-24T05:01:02.930-0400  2019-07-24T04:30:10.927-0400
```

Comment: Thank you. This did it. Python is so cool. I cant believe it was a oneliner code

Comment: Please can you point me to some useful books, resources for such type of information, so i could refer such information in the future

Comment: @user3423407, yes, you may start reading "Python for Data Analysis" book and pandas off. documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have pandas you can do it in pure python with a simple loop:

```
files = {}

with open('/tmp/input.csv') as input:
  reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter=',')
  for (time, action, file) in reader:
    files.setdefault(file, {})
    files[file][action] = time

with open('/tmp/output.csv', 'w') as output:
  writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter=',')
  for (key, val) in files.items():
    writer.writerow((key, val['get'], val['put']))
```